# Mapping owned type in separate table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a typical one-to-one relationship where one side owns the other. The owned side is a weak entity that does not have its own identifier in the database; instead, each record is identified by the owner's PK. Let me illustrate with an example where `video` records *may have* an associated `transcription` record.

```
video (id, description, storage_path)
transcription (video_id, text)
```

Video records have a life of their own. Some of them have a transcription available; most don't. My problem is figuring out how to model this properly with EF Core 3.1. For the `video` mapping I have something like:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Video> builder)
{
    // ...
    builder.OwnsOne(video => video.Transcription).WithOwner();
}
```

How do I map the `transcription` side? When I tried creating a separate mapping for it, I got an error saying `transcription` cannot be mapped as *non-owned*.

Below are the relevant bits of the entity classes, and code-first ORM (using [FluentMigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/)).

#### Video

```cs
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Transcription Transcription { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class VideoTable : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("videos")
            .WithColumn("id").AsInt64().PrimaryKey().Identity()
            // ...
    }
}
```

```cs
public class VideoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Video>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Video> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("videos");
        builder.Property(v => v.Id).HasColumnName("id").IsRequired();
        // ...
        builder.OwnsOne(v => v.Transcription, tbuilder => {
            tbuilder.WithOwner().HasForeingKey("VideoId");
            tbuilder.Property("VideoId").HasColumnName("video_id");
            // ...
            tbuilder.ToTable("transcriptions");
        });
    }
}
```

#### Transcription

```cs
public class Transcription
{
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

```cs
public class TranscriptionTable : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("transcriptions")
            .WithColumn("video_id").AsInt64().PrimaryKey()
            // ...

        Create.ForeignKey("fk_video_transcription")
            .FromTable("transcriptions").ForeignColumn("video_id")
            .ToTable("videos").PrimaryColumn("id");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Note: I'm aware a relationship like this could be implemented with the owned entities' fields incorporated into the owning table. However, there are practical reasons why they should be kept separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owned types are always (can obnly be) configured through their owner entity, and more specifically, through their own builder returned by the `OwnsOne` method or provided as an argument of the `Action<T>` argument of the `OwnsOne` method of the owner entity builder.

Note that you already are using the owned entity builder to call `.WithOwner()` which in turn is used to configure the relationship between the owner and owned. For owned only related configuration like properties, column names, table etc. you use directly the corresponding owned builder fluent methods.

e.g.

```
builder.OwnsOne(video => video.Transcription, ownedBuilder =>
{
    ownedBuilder.WithOwner()
        .HasForeignKey("VideoId");

    ownedBuilder.Property("VideoId")
        .HasColumnName("video_id");

    ownedBuilder.ToTable("Transcription");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, for your insights. However, I still have something wrong. I'm getting the following error: 'The keys {'VideoId'} on 'Transcription' and {'Id'} on 'Video' are both mapped to 'transcriptions.PK_transcriptions' but with different columns ({'video_id'} and {'id'}).' I'm editing the question to add the relevant code-first table creations.

Comment: Where is `"midia_id"` primary key coming from? Probably you have some fluent setup not shown here, because the above is enough to map correctly the model as shown.

Comment: My bad; that's supposed to be 'video_id'. I've already fixed it.

Comment: I've created a separate project focusing just on the scenario presented here. https://github.com/Zunino/csharp-studies/tree/master/16-ef-core-3. VideoContext is currently referring to a local Postgres database. For some reason I have yet to figure out, Npgsql is giving me an exception saying the relation "Videos" does not exist.

Comment: Noticed two things. First, your `VideoMap` is not executed - needs `OnModelCreating` override with `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration` or `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`). Second, this `FluentMigrator` is not standard EF Core component - it can be seen that it still defines column called "Id" on "transcriptions" table which do not exist when using standard EF Core generated migration. Btw, all this really falls outside the scope of the OP question.

Comment: It turns out I was mistakenly calling `ToTable()` for the owned type `Transcription` on the builder of the owning type, `Video`. Thank you once again. I've marked your answer as the correct one as it is full of useful pointers on getting this kind of mapping right.